# upgrading from msmq to rabbitmq

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, msmq, messaging, masstransit

MassTransit does not support MSMQ anymore, and we are all on MSMQ. We need to start upgrading to RabbitMQ, but in the process of the transition we need to have some queues stay MSMQ.

**Is there an effective way of communication between RabbitMQ and MSMQ?**

Comment: It may not be directly relevant to your scenario, but in the general space of MSMQ to RabbitMQ migration/co-existence (or other combinations of queueing technologies), https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/bridge/ is designed exactly for that.

Answer (score 1):

Could not find an existing tool. But how hard to write a simple windows service subscribing & forwarding messages from MSMQ to RabbitMQ? Should really be a small task .

Comment: I agree it should be easy but it's probably not as easy as you might think since a tool like this does not seem to exist

Comment: If you really want to use existing tools. How about to use some tools like https://msmqmngr.codeplex.com/ to priodically export messages to files, and use logstash to montor the files and feed the messages to rabbitmq (logstash has a rabbitmq output). frankly speaking, it might take more time to setup these than to write your own tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a service using MassTransit v2 that sends the messages to RabbitMQ. The your v3 services could consume the messages from RabbitMQ.

The wire format for messages is compatible between v2 and v3 so you can have your services coexist with RabbitMQ and use v2 for services that need to communicate with both message transports.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search gave me [this result](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/MSMQ-Integration-td8790.html). I believe the suggestion here is to roll your own relay to do this as I can't find any MSMQ relays in their [list of dev tools](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#dotnet-dev).